# Bokeh- Datatable updating Label text (0.12.16 ->0.13.0 repair job)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, dataframe, bokeh, kpi

I recently discovered that the new bokeh implemented more detailed hover options for stacked bar charts. Giddy, I updated bokeh right away and incorporated into a nested stacked vbar. Unbeknownst to me though, an unrelated callback that I had implemented under the previous release no longer works, and I do not know how to fix it.

I have a data table, its rows feature several columns with numbers. Selecting rows will sum the total for each selected row's columns, and display it in a `Label`. This aspect no longer works in 0.13.0. Please see a simplified recreation below:

> ```
> Dataframe(df):
> NAME  |  Sales  |  Returns | YEAR
> John      33        3        2018
> Mike      12        3        2018
> Jim       19        9        2018
> Tim        3        1        2017
> Tom       20        0        2017
> ```

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, LabelSet, TapTool, OpenURL,CustomJS, NumberFormatter,
                              TableColumn, DataTable, Slider, CDSView,HoverTool,PreText, BoxSelectTool,
                              Label, Text, Button)
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout, column
from datetime import date
from bokeh.core.properties import expr
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral10

source=ColumnDataSource(data=df)

columns=[TableColumn(field="NAME", title="NAME"),
TableColumn(field="Sales", title= "Sales"),
TableColumn(field="Returns",title="Returns")]

data_table=DataTable(source=source, columns=columns)

def statsline(attr,old,new):
    selection=source.selected.indices
    if selection:
        sales=sum(source.data['Sales'][selection])
        returns=sum(source.data['Returns'][selection])

        income.text="SELECTION | Sales: " + str(sales) + " | Returns: " + str(returns)
p_stat=figure(plot_width=1400, plot_height=60, toolbar_location=None)

income=Label(x_units='screen',y_units='screen',x=90, y=5,
             text="Sales: " + str(df["Sales"][df["YEAR"]==date.today().year].sum()) +"   |   
             Returns: " +str(df["Returns"][df["YEAR"]==date.today().year].sum()),
             text_font_size='20pt')
p_stat.add_layout(income)
source.on_change('selected', statsline)

layout=layout([p_stat],[data_table])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Thanks in advance.
Also, is there a less hacky way to display KPIs in bokeh? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: your suggestion is the solution, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I have changed it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several DataTable related regressions in Bokeh `0.13.0`, they will be addressed in the next release. For the time being (but also going forward), this pattern will work:

```
source.selected.on_change('indices', ...)
```